# Two queries with same tables and join logic but different results

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to get records only in 1 table i.e in A but not in B
case1:

```
 select count(distinct t.col1),count(distinct t.col2)
    from `table1` e
    right join
    (
    select distinct col1,col2
    from `table2_*`
    where _table_suffix between '20180101' and '20181231'
    )t
    on e.col1=t.col1
    where date(timestamp_seconds(ts))>='2018-01-01'
    and e.col1 is null
    ;
```

Case2:

```
select count(distinct col1)
from `table2_*`
where _table_suffix between '20180101' and '20181231'
and col1 not in (
select distinct col1 from `table1`
where date(timestamp_seconds(ts))>='2018-01-01'
)
```

Out of the 2 codes, case2 worked while case1 gave 0 as output. I also tried case 1 as a left join with the tables reversed but the results were the sames 0 rows. I am new to Big Query and the standard sql version and am not sure why this would happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using `NOT IN` you **must not** allow NULL as a value of the "in list"

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT t.col1)
FROM `table2_ * ` AS t
WHERE t._table_suffix BETWEEN '20180101' AND '20181231'
 AND col1 NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT e.col1
  FROM `table1` AS e
  WHERE DATE (timestamp_seconds(e.ts)) >= '2018-01-01'
   AND e.col1 IS NOT NULL
  );
```

Personally I prefer to use `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT t.col1)
FROM `table2_ * ` AS t
WHERE t._table_suffix BETWEEN '20180101' AND '20181231'
 AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL
  FROM `table1` AS e
  WHERE DATE (timestamp_seconds(e.ts)) >= '2018-01-01'
   AND e.col1 = t.col1
  );
```

Note, the subquery select clause here does not need to return any values so `select null` or `select 1` or `select *` are all valid. When using `exits` or `not exists` it is the from & where clauses of the subquery that matter.

Answer (score 1):

> Out of the 2 codes, case2 worked while case1 gave 0 as output.

This is because `NOT IN` returns NULL when there is a NULL in the list. If you don't want this behavior, exclude the NULL values:

```
select count(distinct col1)
from `table2_*`
where _table_suffix between '20180101' and '20181231'
and col1 not in (
select distinct col1 from `table1`
where date(timestamp_seconds(ts))>='2018-01-01'
and col1 IS NOT NULL
)
```